# How To Initialize a JComboBox Whose Items are added Dynamically?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have Created a `JComboBox` and its item are being added dynamically through a `LinkedList`, how to initialize its selected value.

Suppose `"list"` contains `A->B->C->D->null`

I want to intialize the **ComboBox** selected index with **B** (i.e 2nd Item In the list).

I have tried to do it as below

```
ComboBox.setSelectedIndex(1);
```

but I am getting `Exception setSelectedIndex: 1 out of bound`

```
JComboBox ComboBox= new JComboBoX();
LinkedList List = new LinkedList();

getListDataFromDataBase();
//After this List Contains A->B->C->D->null

for(int i=1;i<=List.getSize();i++)
{
    Object Item = List.getValueAt(i);
    ComboBox.addItem(Item);
}

ComboBox.setSelectedIndex(1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure elements are added into the `comboBox`, using `addItem()`.

Here's a small snippet:

```
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Demo {

  public static void main(String[] a) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JComboBox jComboBox1 = new JComboBox();
    jComboBox1.addItem("Item 0");
    jComboBox1.addItem("Item 1");
    jComboBox1.addItem("Item 2");
    jComboBox1.addItem("Item 3");
    jComboBox1.addItem("Item 4");
    jComboBox1.addItem("Item 5");

    Object cmboitem = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println(cmboitem);

    frame.add(jComboBox1);

    jComboBox1.setSelectedIndex(4);
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Adding from a `linkedList`

```
for(int i = 0; i < linkedList.size(); i++)
   comboBox.addItem(linkedList.get(i).toString());
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Uma kanth, Thanks for helping but this doesn't solve my my problem

Comment: What is the Problem, Is your comboBox displaying the list which has the elements without setting the index?

Comment: If I am not setting any index then it work just fine, but if I try to set any index I am getting out of bound exception, i am even checking the size of the list before setting the index

Comment: should be used DefaultComboBoxModel, MutableComboBoxModel for handlig all of the events ...

Comment: Hi mKorbel I have not specified any Model while creating JComboBox Object , do I have to explicitly specify DefaultComboBox Model ?

Comment: thank you all for helping, Uma kanth your solution solved my problem thanks. My list was also building dynamically so, before updating the new list to ComboBox I was setting the Index.

Comment: `i = 1; i <= list.getSize()` must be the mistake?